# C# substring throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, string

This is my code:

```
private string title(string pth) //I'm passing a path
{
    pth = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pth); // I need an exact filename with no extension
    return pth.Substring(pth.IndexOf('-')+1, pth.Length).Trim(); // trying to return everything after '-'
}
```

It throws an exception. I have no idea why. It's an extremely easy way to get the title from filename, but it's not working.

I've tried `pth.Length-1`, but it's not working either.

Comment: What is the exception? also, what path are you passing into it?

Comment: First check for the existence of `-` ?

Comment: it's: "system.argumentoutofrangeexception index and length must refer to a location within the string"

Comment: @SrinivasThatiparthy - yeah, I added "if" statement, but it's not the reason, because every file has "-" in its name, but yeah - it's a good tip, thank you :)

Comment: @SrinivasThatiparthy wouldn't mater since -1 + 1 = 0

Comment: Isn't the use of [file without extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) is to get file name without extension?) What are you doing with these other chopping offs? ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the version of the [`String.Substring` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) that allows you to specify the number of characters you wish to extract.

However, you're providing the `length` parameter as the entire length of the string itself -- hence the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

If you use [this version of `String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx), you can provide a single parameter (`startIndex`) and you'll automatically get the rest of the string, starting at the index you provide.

So you can change your code from this:

```
return pth.Substring(pth.IndexOf('-')+1, pth.Length).Trim();
```

To this:

```
return pth.Substring(pth.IndexOf('-')+1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Substring(int index, int length)`, the `length` should be the length of the substring, not the length of the entire string.

You want:

```
int index = pth.IndexOf('-');
return pth.Substring(index + 1, pth.Length - index - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are trying to retrieve the substring that is shorter than the length you specified. Also, if the character `'-'`is at the end of the string, you will get the exception because the `index+1` will be outside of the string.
This will help:

```
private string title(string pth) //I'm passing a path
    {
        pth = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pth); // I need an exact filename with no extension
        string retStr = string.Empty;
        if(pth.IndexOf('-')<pth.Length-1)
        {
              retStr = pth.Substring(pth.IndexOf('-')+1).Trim(); // trying to return everything after '-'
        }
        return retStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a Regular Expression in this case.  Something like:

```
private static string title(string pth)
{
   pth = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pth); // I need an exact filename with no extension
   Match m = Regex.Match(pth, @".*\-(?<suffix>.*)$");

   Group suffix = m.Groups["suffix"];
   return suffix.Success ? suffix.Value : pth;
}
```

Much cleaner.

Comment: I wouldn't call this cleaner. Also if this should work as in question you should return `pth` rather than `null` if does not exist.

Comment: Well, definitely a lot less checking of various lengths and worrying about string offsets.  I guess if you're not used to regular expressions, it could be more convoluted.  Good point about returning `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your exception is, but I'm assuming that `-` doesn't exist in your string.

If you review the documention for `String.IndexOf` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx), you'll see:

> The zero-based index position of value if that string is found, or -1 if it is not

When you do a `subString` with a `-1` start index, it will throw an exception.

I would check for the existence of `-` first, then if found do your substring:

```
if(pth.IndexOf('-') != -1)
{
    //Substring code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should tell us what your exception is.  that will help

```
pth.Substring(pth.IndexOf('-')+1, pth.Length)
```

looks like it will throw an exception because it will try to take a substring beyond the length.

try

```
pth.Substring(pth.IndexOf('-')+1)
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to the String.Substring method is the length of the substring.  The length of the substring in this case should always be *less* than the length of the pth string.  You probably meant to do this:

```
private string title(string pth) //I'm passing a path
{
    pth = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pth);
    return pth.Substring(pth.IndexOf('-')+1, pth.Length - pth.IndexOf('-') - 1).Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your code like this:

```
private string title(string pth) //I'm passing a path
{
  pth = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pth);
  var indexOfDash = pth.IndexOf('-') + 1; // Add this line
  return pth.Substring(indexOfDash, pth.Length - indexOfDash).Trim();
}
```